# How to replace a line that has a specific text

Tags: python

I want to search for particular text and replace the line if the text is present in that line.

In this code I replace line 125, but want to replace dynamically according to the text:

```
file = open("config.ini", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
lines[125] = "minimum_value_gain = 0.01" + '\n'
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
```

How do I make it that if a line has:

```
minimum_value_gain =
```

then replace that line with:

```
minimum_value_gain = 0.01
```

Comment: Check out how to use the `if` statement in python. And also how to write to files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for you to manually parse a `config.ini` file textually. You should use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) to make things much simpler. This library reads the file for you, and in a way converts it to a dict so processing the data is much easier. For your task you can do something like:

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
for section in config:
    if config.has_option(section, "minimum_value_gain"):
        config.set(section, "minimum_value_gain", "0.01")

with open("config.ini", 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are replacing complete line so if statement will do the trick for you, no need to replace text

```
#updated make sure one line doesn't have both values

file = open("config.ini", "r")
lines=file.readlines()
newlines = []
for line in lines:
    if "minimum_value_gain" in line:
        line = "minimum_value_gain = 0.01" + '\n'
    if "score_threshold" in line:
        line = "Values you want to add"+'\n'
    newlines.append(line)
f.writelines(newlines)
f.close()
```

Comment: lets say in the text folder minimum_value_gain = 0.05
when i run this it makes it 


minimum_value_gain = 0.01 = 0.05

Comment: that is because you are replacing "minimum_value_gain" with this "minimum_value_gain = 0.01" + '\n', let me update answer for you

Comment: Where do you open your file for writing ?

Comment: I am modifying script shared in question i am sure it is portion of script not complete one rather it would give variable f not defined error

Comment: Both `lines` and `newlines` are not necessary and take-up memory for nothing. Instead of `lines` just do `for line in file` and instead of `newlines` just do `f.write(line)`

Comment: i believe 'f.write(line)' will write last line of text or last interval of loop to file, isn't that so?correct me if i am wrong, i am just self taught trying to learn stuff here..

Comment: Thanks and don’t forget mark as correct answer by clicking the tick ✅

Comment: lets say I wanted to put an if statement and if that if statement is true then it will change 2 lines that have a specific words, can you just add another line to your code that changes another text called "score_threshold"
I tried to add it but it always just ignored it and never really changed "score_threshold" in my txt, basically make it so it changes minimum value gain and score threshold, this will be the last question and if it works ill mark it 
as right answer thank you for all help ive learned a lot from your code.

Comment: when I keep calling the script when I press a button on my gui it just keeps duplicating the config.ini but everytime it duplicates config it changes the text in the other duplicate
anyway I can make it stop copy and pasting the whole config.ini again and again
for example if I press a button to change value gain to 0.01 it will copy the config and change value gain then paste it again so its duplicating

Comment: This is because you are using file to open and saving it as f rather try ‘file.writelines(newlines)’ and ‘file.close()’

Comment: @AssadAli In my previous comment I meant inside the loop. Replace `newlines.append(line)` with `f.write(line)`. And you can iterate over lines directly from the file as `for line in file:` and this will save you both the lists

Answer (score 0):

- Set the string you would like to look for (`match_string = 'example'`)
- Have a list `output_list` that is empty
- Use `with open(x,y) as z:` (this will automatically close the file after completion)
- `for each line in file.readlines()` - run through each line of the file
- The `if` statement adds your replacement line if the `match_string` is in the line, else just the adds the line

NOTE: All variables can be any name that is not reserved (don't call something just 'list')

```py
match_string = 'example'
output_list = []

with open("config.ini", "r") as file:
   for line in file.readlines():
       if match_string in line:
           output_list.append('minimum_value_gain = 0.01\n')
       else:
           output_list.append(line)
```

Maybe not ideal for the first introduction to Python (or more readable) - But I would have done the problem as follows:

```
with open('config.ini', 'r') as in_file:
    out_file = ['minimum_value_gain = 0.01\n' if 'example' in line else line for line in in_file.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit messy and not optimized but get's the job the, first readlines and inserts the `next_text` to the given pos(**line**). If the line doesn't exists Raises IndexError, else writes to the file

```
def replace_in_file(filename: str, search_text: str, string_to_add: str) -> None:
    with open(filename, "r+") as file_to_write:
        lines = file_to_write.readlines()
        file_to_write.seek(0)
        file_to_write.truncate()
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith(search_text):
                line = line.rstrip("\n") + string_to_add + "\n"
            file_to_write.write(line)


replace_in_file("sdf.txt", "minimum_value_gain", " = 0.01")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the regex library of Python.
Here is an example.

It is better not to read and write in the same file, that is not good practice. Write in a different file then eventually rename it.

```py
import re

pattern = 'minimum_value_gain'
string_to_replace = 'minimum_value_gain = 0.01\n'

file = open("config.ini", "r")
fileout = open("new_config.ini", "a")

lines=file.readlines()
newlines = [string_to_replace if re.match(pattern, line) else line for line in lines]

f.close()
fileout.writelines(lines)
fileout.close()
```

You can rename the file afterwards :

```py
import os
os.remove("config.ini")
os.rename("new_config.ini", "config.ini")
```

Comment: Using `re` is a bit of an overkill for something that can be done using `sub in string` or `string.startswith(sub)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Well, in a way, now I do not know if it is more memory and time consuming. Perhaps it is better to write directly in a file rather than saving the result in a list. Anyway, you solution is the best one.

Comment: Thanks for that :) Anyway I believe regex will usually be slower, especially because of pattern compilation. A slight improvement will be to do `re.compile(pattern)` before the loop and then `pattern.match(line)` inside the loop (BTW you forgot the `line` in `re.match(pattern, <line>)`

Answer (score -1):

To replace a specific text in a string

```
a = 'My name is Zano'
b = a.replace('Zano', 'Zimmer')
```

Comment: He wants to replace a line completely, not just a part of a string